# Where Can I Get Started in Game Dev. with Java?

Tags: java

For a while now, I have wanted o learn Java game development, my questions are:

1. Where do I start (I have very basic/basic knowledge of Java)
2. What do I need to know to make a 2d platformer similar to Spelunky, or Super Mario?
3. Any other tips you can offer.

Thank you so much, and I'm very sorry if posted this in the wrong place or asked the wrong thing, I just need some help starting out.

Thanks.

Comment: There are some interesting projects that can manage the plumbing of game development, personally I would look at jMonkey

Comment: As a Java aficionado, I hate to break ranks, but you may be better off with HTML5/CSS3/JavaScript than with Java. Also voting to close question as opinion based. It's not a bad question per se, and so I have neither up-voted it nor down-voted it, but it doesn't belong on this site.

Answer (score 1):

I would highly recommend

http://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/ for some basic framework to help you get started. Its great for 2D like you said you wanted to do. There are some 3D frameworks and engines to help you get started, but I would recommend getting whichever one you want to focus on first.

also http://www.java-gaming.org/ is a great board for various java game related things.

While many will say you should further master your knowledge of Java first, and I do agree to some extent.  So long as you have patience, you can do both at the same time, understanding that some basic things might take longer than normal and you may do things in some less than ideal ways.

Also once you become pretty good at 1 language and making a game,  its usually pretty decently portable to any language and most gamedev environment.  So don't let anyone persuade you toward 1 or the other. In the beginning, it doesn't matter. Just spend some time working on something, then later you can decide to move around or not.

Answer (score 1):

There are several great series that you can watch that create simple games and you can learn how they work and make your own similiar games:

[Thenewboston Tutorials](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hBhAWTSu104&list=PLA331A6709F40B79D)

[MrCrayfish's Tutorials](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HHBJuqzYxXI)

And if you want to learn more java before getting into game development look at thenewbostons other tutorials (I recommend doing this first).